# Eigen - divide each (sparse) matrix row by its corresponding diagonal element

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, sparse-matrix

Using the Eigen library in C++, given a sparse matrix `A`, what is the most efficient way (row-wise operations? how to?) to compute a sparse matrix `B` such that `B(i, j) = A(i, j) / A(i, i)` ? That is, divide each row `i` by the corresponding diagonal element `A(i, i)`.
It would be helpful to know how to do it both in-place (replacing entries in `A`) and out-of-place (creating a new sparse matrix `B`).

My sparse matrix is defined as:

```
typedef double Real;
typedef Eigen::SparseMatrix<Real> SparseMatrixR;
```

Thank you,
m.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In other words you want to extract the diagonal of A, view it as a diagonal matrix, and apply its inverse to A:

```
A = A.diagonal().asDiagonal().inverse() * A;
```

This operation should be slightly more efficient if A is rowmajor.